# copy the recently modified file from source to destination in Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to copy the recently modified file from source to destination.

**Constraint:** All the files starting with same name in the source folder.
Example: Source - `C:\Source` and is having files like  `sys1239_5241.KNL`, `sys1234_8741.KNL`

So how to copy latest modified files in batch file and modification will happen in minutes not in dates.

Comment: if you just want to copy modified files you can use `xcopy /d`

Comment: please explain more clearly: `modification will happen in minutes`

Comment: It will copy file modified according to specified date.But i want file which is modified according in terms of minutes and seconds.

Comment: and how many are `latest modified files` !?

Comment: only one modified file.

Answer (score 8):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "C:\Source\*.KNL"') do set "LatestModifiedFile=%%~i"
echo copy "C:\Source\%LatestModifiedFile%" "X:\destination\path"
```

..remove `echo` if it looks good.

Comment: Maybe change del to copy, if that's what he wants to do.

Comment: @foxidrive thanks again. I can't understand the upvoters, imo they didn't read the question and my answer completely :(. I will better finish my service here for today, we have 35°C (95°F) and no air conditioning :->

Comment: Is it possible to add also condition to copy only if the file was created today?

Answer (score 0):

The following works well.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "C:\Teste_1\*"') do set "LatestModifiedFile=%%~i"
copy "C:\Teste_1\%LatestModifiedFile%" "C:\Teste_2\"
pause
```